# In the Stochastic-Local Volatility (SLV/LSV) calibration procedure, which surface is used when calibrating the Leverage function

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, calibration, local-volatility, volatility-surface

Before we match the leverage function $L(S_t,t)$ to the implied volatility surface generated from the market, we are supposed to calibrate the pure Heston parameters, $(\theta, \kappa, v_0, \rho, \xi)$. Since the Heston parameters don't usually match the market surface 1:1, the surface generated from the calibrated heston parameters will be *different* than the market surface (otherwise there would be no need for SLV). Then when calibrating $L(S_t,t)$, do we use the market IV surface, or the surface generated from the Heston parameters we calibrated?

I would think it would still be the market surface, but I am not sure because the parameters are from a different surface...

Comment: The implementations I am familiar with first match the market with a local volatility model function (using Dupire’s formula). Afterward, the leverage surface is found, using the stochastic parameters, such that the SLV joint density has the same marginal distributions as the LV model.

Comment: @AKdemy I am aware of that method, I believe it’s similar to this paper: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877750317301709. Although, I was following the procedure from this paper: https://faculty.fordham.edu/rchen/Fenics.pdf. Which first calibrates the pure Heston model and then calibrates  the leverage function. Although they aren’t explicit with what surface they calibrate the leverage function to, as in do they calibrate the leverage function to the surface generated from the calibrated Heston parameters or the one from the original market volatilities .

Comment: Doesn't having the same marginal distribution as the LV model imply that it's market volatilities? See for example [Gyongy](https://www.scirp.org/reference/referencespapers?referenceid=2075736). In any case, you need to calibrate to the market vol, otherwise you cannot even price vanilla markets properly with your model. You may want to calibrate the mixing weights to barrier option prices beforehand but the end goal is to also calibrate to the market of vanillas (which is the main reference you have).